# Mysql возвратить время со сдвигом timezone

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть ли способ возвращать время в зависимости от временной зоны? Я понимаю что есть timestampz, но в данном случае datetime

т.е. хочу получить время по москве (3) исходя из текущего сохраненного (5) где время по москве 14:00

```
select dt_create + interval 2 hour from t where dt_create - interval 2 hour = 14:00
```

но загвоздка в том, что я не знаю какие поля - это время. могу ли я в зависимости от типа поля добавлять интервал?

Comment: Пока не очень понятно, вы в каком часовом поясе данные храните? в UTC?

Comment: про типы полей вопрос не понятен. вы же все равно в запросе будете указывать конкретные поля, значит предварительно можете посмотреть их тип. Или вы хотите как то динамически генерировать запрос исходя из заранее не известной структуры таблицы и ваш вопрос заключается в том как определить тип поля

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- **Часовые пояса относятся к уровню презентации.**
  Большинство вашего кода не должно заниматься часовыми поясами или местным временем, оно должно передавать **Unix**-время как оно есть.
- Когда измеряете время, измеряйте Unix-время. Это UTC. Его просто
  получить (системными функциями). Оно не имеет часовых поясов или
  летнего времени (и високосных секунд).
- Когда храните время, храните Unix-время. Это одно число.
- Если вы хотите сохранить время, пригодное для чтения человеком
  (например, в логах), постарайтесь сохранить его вместе с
  Unix-временем, а не вместо.
- Когда отображаете время, всегда включайте в него смещение часового
  пояса. Формат времени без смещения бесполезен.
- Системные часы не точны.
- Вы в сети? Системные часы каждой другой машины не точны по-разному.
- Системные часы могут, и будут, перепрыгивать вперёд и назад во
  времени из-за вещей, которые вне вашего контроля. Ваша программа
  должна быть разработана таким образом, чтобы пережить это.
- Отношение количества секунд системных часов к количеству настоящих
  секунд — не точно и может меняться. В основном это зависит от
  температуры.
- MySQL хранит столбцы типа DATETIME в виде упакованных в числа
  значений «YYYYMMDD HHMMSS» Если вы озаботились хранением отметок
  времени, храните их как целое число и используйте для преобразования
  функции UNIX_TIMESTAMP() и FROM_UNIXTIME().

[Что должен знать о времени каждый программист](https://habrahabr.ru/post/123461/)